# Dynamically adding array to multidimensional array

Tags: c++

I have problem with assign array as a element of a multidimensional array.
Code below doesn't work as I except, but if I change types from unsigned char to int, everything is working fine.

```
unsigned char CH0[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
unsigned char CH1[4] = { 8, 7, 6, 5 };

unsigned char** mPins;
unsigned char index;

void init(unsigned char size)
{
    mPins = new unsigned char*[size];
    index =0;
}

void setup(unsigned char* array){
    mPins[index] = array;
    index++;
}

main() {
   init(2);
   setup(CH0);
   setup(CH1);
}
```

Comment: don't mark C++ questions as C

Comment: "doesn't work as I except" is not a detailed explanation of your problem, I'm afraid.

Comment: You should've include the printing part to help us find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code prints nothing because `char` is supposed to be used to store characters. And characters with the codes you are using are unprintable.

This code [works](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/0o31pOrqTBm099uL):

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned char CH0[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
unsigned char CH1[4] = { 8, 7, 6, 5 };

unsigned char** mPins;
unsigned char index;

void init(unsigned char size)
{
    mPins = new unsigned char*[size];
    index =0;
}

void setup(unsigned char* array){
    mPins[index] = array;
    index++;
}

int main() {
    init(2);
    setup(CH0);
    setup(CH1);
    for(int i = 0; i < 2 ; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            std::cout << (int)mPins[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 
8 7 6 5
```

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer.